# Best way to do master/slave in Slick 3 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm looking for the best way to configure Slick 3 with a typical master/slave mysql schema. Basically I want to send writes to a mysql server and reads to another one and trust the two servers are synchronized.

I've readed [this][1] but I think is for Slick 2. I've readed the Slick official doc and I don't see anything about this topic.

Now, with one database (no master slave) i have this in application.conf.

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/new_chat"
        user = "new_chat"
        password = "new_chat"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm executing queries like this:

```
PersistenceUtils.run(conversationMembers += conversationMember)
```

PersistenceUtils:

```
def run[R](a: DBIOAction[R, NoStream, Nothing])
    (implicit chatContext: ChatContext, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[R] = {

    val result = chatContext.db.run(a)


    result.onFailure({ case e => logger.error(s"error executing query: ${a.getDumpInfo.mainInfo}", e) })
    result
  }
```

There is a way to do this with configuration in application.conf? I do not want master/slave in dev, only in staging and production. I've read about a ReplicationDriver but I don't see anything in Slick doc :S

Anybody can give me some clue? :P

Thank you

Comment: Isn't it common to put the master and a slave behind a load balancer (see also [this blog post](http://agiletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/mysql-load-balancing-and-read-write.html)). The load balancer can figure out to which server the request should be sent. If you do this, the logic for the load balancing does not clutter your code base (since you're only connecting to the loadbalancer). Plus you can still connect to a database directly in development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure your jdbc url like below:

```
jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/<database>
```

And set the driver to:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
```

Once you are done with the above, all that you have to do is to mark the queries, that need to go to slave machines, as **readonly**. So, all jdbc connections that are readonly are delegated to slave machines and the ones that are not readonly are sent to the master.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for you answer, can you please elaborate on your comment "all that you have to do is to mark the queries"?

Comment: By that, I meant, you need to mark the JDBC connections as readonly. If you want a query to be executed against a slave node, you need to mark the JDBC connection as readonly so it gets executed on a slave node. More details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html).